# Ruby on Rails examples for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails at the moment.

Being a tester by profession (JMeter, Selenium etc.), I'd like to know if there any good example Ruby on Rails projects that I can run for the purposes of trying out JMeter and Cucumber and other Load and Functional test tools.

The kind of thing that just does stuff like signs up users, books tickets for something or other, does searches... has admin functions...

Not important exactly what, just that it's relatively easy to install, and it gives me a good chance to exercise JMeter and Web Driver.

Might be nice if it:

1)  Uses RoR best practices to help me learn

2)  PostgresQL DB

3)  Bootstrap framework

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: Check out my project [ruby5kdev](https://github.com/prakashmurthy/ruby5kdev); it has most of the things you have listed out.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look on [gitlab](http://gitlab.org/) project. Being as complicated as github it's completely open and has good test coverage with rspec.